generateStaticParams() not working in NextJs/TypeScript
I have a products page in my NextJs app. Dynamic routes should get rendered statically using generateStaticParams(), however they do not. when I run "npm run build" it says "Generating static pages (3/3)"when it should be much more than 3 and also when I deploy the project on Vercel and click on a single product card. instead of it taking me to the corresponding product page, it gives me "500 internal server error". Also, it used to work before, but now I wrote some new types, otherwise I did not touch anything else related to this page, but it stopped working.
import Image from "next/image"

export async function generateStaticParams() {
    const res = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products')
    const products = await res.json()

    const paths = products.products.map((product: {id: number}) => ({
        id: `${product.id}`,
    }))

    return paths
}


async function getProduct(id: number) {
    const res = await fetch(`https://dummyjson.com/products/${id}`)
    const data = await res.json()
    return data
}


export default async function Service({ params }: { params: {id: number} }) {
    
    const product = await getProduct(params.id)

    return (
        <div style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column"}}>
            <h1>{product.title}</h1>
            <Image src={product.thumbnail} alt="asd" width={400} height={400}/>
            <span>In stock: {product.stock}</span>
        </div>
    )
}

This is the parent:
"use client";

import '@/styles/BlogServices.css'
import ServiceSection from '@/components/ServiceSection.tsx'
import React from 'react'


export default function Services() {
    
    interface Product {
        id: number,
        title: string,
        description: string,
        price: number,
        image: string,
        category: string
    }


    const [searchedService, setSearchedService] = React.useState<Product[]>([])
    const [defaultService, setDefaultService] = React.useState<Product[]>([])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            setSearchedService(res.products)
            setDefaultService(res.products)
        })
    },[])



    function handleSearch (value:string) {
        setSearchedService(defaultService.filter(item => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())))
    }

    return (
        <div className="services-page-container">
            <div className="blog-service-page-title-container parent-flex-column-center dark:bg-slate-900">
                <span className="blog-service-page-short-title">SERVICES</span>
                <h1 className="blog-service-page-title font-bold">Choose and book service with us</h1>
                <p className="blog-service-page-desc text-page-subtitle text-xl dark:text-slate-400">Subscribe to learn about new product features, the latest in technology, solutions, and updates.</p>
            </div>
            <ServiceSection 
                servicePage
                descStyle='services-section-desc'
                handleSearch={handleSearch}
                searchedService={searchedService}
                defaultService={defaultService}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

And this is the card component itself:
"use client";

import servicearrow from '../public/assets/servicearrow.svg'
import '../styles/Card.css'
import Image, { StaticImageData } from 'next/image'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

interface ServiceCard {
    id?: number;
    title: string;
    desc: string;
    date?: string;
    img: string | StaticImageData;
    imgStyle: string;
    contStyle: string;
    descStyle: string;
    servicepage?: boolean;
    handleClick?: () => void;
}

export default function ServiceCard(props: ServiceCard) {

    const router = useRouter()

    function handleClick() {
        props.servicepage && router.push(`/services/${props.id}`)
    }
    
    return (
        <div className={`card-container ${props.contStyle} dark:bg-slate-600`} onClick={handleClick}>
            <Image src={props.img} className={`card-img ${props.imgStyle}`} width={300} height={300} alt=''/>
            <span className='card-date'>{props.date}</span>
            <h3 className='text-xl font-bold mb-5 dark:text-slate-200'>{props.title}</h3>
            <p className={`card-description ${props.descStyle} dark:text-slate-50`}>{props.desc}</p>
            <span className='text-service-card-orange flex mt-auto dark:text-orange-700'>View full information <Image className='ml-6' src={servicearrow} alt="" /></span>
        </div>
    )
}

This is the file structure:

NOTE: "services" is the products page I am talking about.
I am new to TypeScript, but still I don't think adding some new types should have caused this to stop working. Thanks in advance.
I do not even know what to try, because I can not find anything to help me out online and not being familiar with typescript makes it even worse.

the functions you named like generateStaticParams() or getServerSideProps() are for previous version of NextJs which is also known as page-router .
but now you are using app-router which is added to nextJs after version 13.
when you use app folder for your route the functions of page router are not available. you need to change your code based on app-router or you have to use page-router by changing your app into page.
you completely mixed up app-router and page-router read the NextJs Doc it would help a lot .

So if I understand correctly, there is no way to statically generate some pages in this new version?

no ! there exist everything we had previously like ssg- ssr - isr in next app router but in a brand new way , not with old functions and methods

generateStaticParams is perfectly valid for the App Router in Next >= 13 as per the official docs:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params
